# Is there a way to add some padding to Chrome or Firefox between the top of the actual window and the top of the tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, vmware-player

I'm using Chrome on a VM (I can also use FF) and there is a toolbar that has a tendency to get stuck at the top of the page (it won't retreat back into hiding like it's supposed to) and that makes closing tabs really, really annoying.  I've spent hours trying to figure out how to fix the toolbar, but I can't find anything that works for me.

So I'm wondering if I can simply change/add something in Chrome to basically shift the tabs down a little bit while the window is fullscreen like usual.  I technically could just not maximize the window and shorten it, but I figured if there was a way to do it like this it would make my life ever so slightly easier. The height of the toolbar is pretty much the height of the tabs on Chrome, so anything that could shift them down (i.e. add some padding above them) that is roughly the same height as the tabs themselves would probably work.

Anyone have a way to do this?  I could also switch to firefox if there is a way to do it there.

Comment: How to hide the toolbar in vmware: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2232920

Comment: see also this answer: http://superuser.com/a/489520/158420

Comment: @Gael I don't want to hide it though as I frequently have to switch between my VM and my regular OS.  Unless that would allow me to do this still.

Comment: you can still switch with a shortcut: http://superuser.com/a/645400/158420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `--window-position` command option: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-position:

```
google-chrome --window-position=0,200
```

The window must not be maximized (I did not found a flag to do that).

How to do that depends on the OS: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags

It is not a perfect solution and a simpler way to get the same result is to position the Chrome window yourself. The position should be stored when you close it.